# how to add AutoCompleteExtender in Textbox control in a repeater in asp 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I m working **asp 2.0**. For Dynamically Created Textbox i worked out same the AutoCompleteExtender.
So for i have been tired in repeater control.But i m unable to finished it.If u anyone have idea give ur suggeston.Below is the sample code for that i need add the **AutoCompleteExtender** for the **TextBox** "**txt_username**".

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeaterentry" runat="server"  >
<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox id="txt_username" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("USER_NAME") %>'  > </asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: for marking your own answer days after I had already provided the answer you "found".

Comment: Downvoters: please add an explanatory comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

.aspx markup in your repeater:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="autoComplete1" 
    TargetControlID="txt_username"
    ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
    CompletionInterval="1000"
    EnableCaching="true"
    CompletionSetCount="20" 
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
    DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">

</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(
    string prefixText, int count, string contextKey) {
//todo
 }
```

Comment: here you want to take the textbox id from repeater control.How to take?

Comment: It was specified in the markup. i.e. txt_username. Also, why did you reply to your own question saying you used basically the solution I gave you?